Как изменить строчку HTML кода через tampermonkey на чужом сайте, чтобы при нажатии на определенную кнопку, открывалась моя ссылка в автомат режиме?
Суть такая, на сайте есть кнопка "сбп" (прикрепил скриншот):

Код этой кнопки:
<a class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained sc-fznWOq sc-fzolEj dmgWTu MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-fullWidth" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" data-test="payment-sbp-button" href="/ru/payment-method" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "сбп)  переменная href = " ссылка"  в автоматическом режиме через tampermonkey  вставляла мою ссылку в href, и меня перебрасывали на нужный мне сайт.
Примерный код, который я использовал в tampermonkey:
// ==UserScript==

// @name         New Userscript

// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/

// @version      2024-08-19

// @description  try to take over the world!

// @author       You

// @match        https://store.standoff2.com/ru/payment-method

// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackoverflow.com

// @grant        none

// ==/UserScript==

    (function() {
    'use strict';

    const href = document.querySelector( 'href "/ru/payment-method"' );

    if (href) {
        href.type = 'href = "https://www.google.com.ua/?hl=u"';
   }
})();

Но он, не срабатывает.
Исходники tampermonkey брал тут : Как изменить строчку кода HTML на чужом сайте tampermonkey?
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать доступа к сайту нет, сайт не мой. Мне нужно чтобы эти изменения были только у меня...

Посмотрите, как правильно составляются селекторы по атрибуту. А потом еще как заменить значение этого атрибута


Не совсем ясна суть вопроса.
Что за селектор такой?
Что за атрибут type?

// Селектор видимо такой?
let elem = document.querySelector('a[href="/ru/payment-method"]');
if (elem !== null) { // elem или твой `<a class="MuiButtonBase-root...` или NULL
   // Поменять атрибут href можно вот так.
   elem.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com.ua/?hl=u')
   // Кликнуть на кнопку можно вот так.
   elem.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
}

